# AWS Fargate Task, healthCheck with scratch docker base image and no CMD

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, aws-fargate

I have my golang application containerized and the last image in the Dockerfile is the `scratch`, since its `scratch` and it has no shell nor curl or anything, I've decided to write my own simple `healthcheck` binary. The problem is that the `healthcheck` seems to work fine, but my container is still flagged as unhealthy, I couldn't find any examples that don't use the `CMD` and `curl` so I am guessing that I am missing some detail in my setup to properly mark the health check as succeeded

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:%s/health", os.Getenv("PORT")))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("healthcheck failed, status: ", res.StatusCode)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

And in my server I have the following endpoint

```golang
func registerHealthcheckEndpoint(mux *http.ServeMux) {
    mux.HandleFunc("/health", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        slog.InfoContext(r.Context(), "healthcheck")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
}
```

If I check my logs on my ECS task

```
{"time":"2024-01-24T07:48:12.88270338Z","level":"INFO","msg":"healthcheck"}
```

I can see that this endpoint is being hit, and its working fine returning http status `200`.

But my health is marked as unhealthy and it says that the container failed the health checks.

This very endpoint works fine for the target group healthchecks

```js
        svc.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
            path: "/health",
            interval: Duration.seconds(60),
        })
```

Here is how I registered my `healthCheck` on my container

```js
            healthCheck: {
                command: [
                    '/app/healthcheck'
                ],
                interval: Duration.seconds(60),
            }
```

Here is my docker file

Here is the dockerfile that builds this

```dockerfile
FROM golang:1.21 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY ./internal ./internal

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build  -installsuffix cgo -o ./main internal/cmd/app/main.go
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -installsuffix cgo -o ./healthcheck internal/cmd/healthcheck/main.go

FROM alpine:3.6 as alpine

RUN apk add -U --no-cache ca-certificates

FROM scratch

COPY --from=alpine /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/main ./main
COPY --from=builder /app/healthcheck ./healthcheck

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

EDIT:

It seems `CMD` is mandatory

> A string array representing the command that the container runs to determine if it is healthy. The string array must start with CMD to run the command arguments directly, or CMD-SHELL to run the command with the container's default shell.

[From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html#API_HealthCheck_Contents)

Is there any way to achieve what I want? I already switched to `alpine` for the time being and using `wget` but I'd love to see a solution

Comment: Long shot: Maybe try to define the `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile as your app binary as well, and use something like cobra or else to have 2 commands (`serve` and `health`). So that you can start your app with `/app serve` or run healthcheck with `/app health`. Set your healthcheck command as `health`. Perhaps then Fargate will be able to run the command. I'm wondering if it's trying to use some default `sh` or `bash` since `ENTRYPOINT` is not defined.

Comment: Also maybe your healthcheck command is badly formatted: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_healthcheck.

Looks like it should be something like ["CMD", "some-command"]

Comment: Yeah I added in the edit that `CMD` is mandatory, even though ideally it wouldn't be. It just seems that my way of doing it is not currently supported sadly. I had similar idea with a bash script and having -- health or -- serve app but I decided to just switch to alpine. You can write up your comment as an alternative approach and I'll accept it as solution for future readers

Comment: Yeah I had the same issue a while back, but I'm not sure I ever got it to work with scratch images. I remember ... scratching my head a lot over this, also think I switched to alpine. I'd rather not put it as an answer because I'm not sure it would actually work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing with all the places you can set the health check in AWS for ECS EC2/Fargate service.

Taking a closer look at the AWS documents for setting the HealthCheck in a [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-healthcheck.html) for a container that runs as part of a service, you use any app without a shell like so:

```json
{
    "HealthCheck": {
        "Command": [
            "CMD",
            "/app/healthcheck"
        ],
        "Interval": 5,
        "Timeout": 2,
        "Retries": 3
    }
}
```

NOTE: The capital H in HealthCheck, it may be case sensitive, so follow the docs example. Also, CMD is not what you may think here, it does not mean that sh, bash, or some other is required, rather the opposite. The docs are saying use CMD if you do NOT want to use sh or bash, but run the app directly.

If your app/task running in fargate is not part of a service, then you can set the health check in the Dockerfile like so:

```
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=3s \
  CMD /app/healthcheck || exit 1
```

Health checks require an exit 0 or 1 code.

Please note that making a Golang binary for your health-check may be bigger than the curl binary. Though the size difference may be negligible.

See Dockerfile documentation for more info on [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)

How to Check health when running container locally:

Run `docker ps -a`
[image]

Comment: The one that you set on the container is ignored by the Fargate, so that one is not the problem. The health check failing is due to there having to be a `CMD` option which I don't have and can't have since I am running a server on a `scratch` base.

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic Why do you believe that you cannot use CMD with a scratch image, is that in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: There is no `CMD-CHELL` in `scratch` image, and the `CMD` is your own `CMD` that you define, so you can have a `CMD` but you have to write it yourself, either a script or a binary with a flag like `myapp --server` and `myapp --healthcheck` . From my understanding

Comment: You can add whatever shell you want to any image that starts from scratch. The scratch is not an image that you can pull but more of a no-op that tells Docker to use your next RUN or COPY as the first layer in the image. Again, this just means you can define the CMD or CMD-SHELL by what you COPY into the image.

Comment: Updated my answer after reviewing the AWS task definition docs to understand where it looks for the healthcheck and how to set it to an app of choice without the use of shell app.